# Where to store Refresh Token and Client Secret safely?

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have an Asp.Net - Web API configured to distribute Refresh tokens using OAuth and Owin. I want to call the API from my applications on the server side (they are not mobile). My idea is to retrieve the refresh token once the application starts (in a Startup class for example) and to store it somewhere on the server.

**Where is by standard a good place to store the Refresh tokens and the Client Secret?** 
Do I need to encrypt the refresh token or is it safe to store it clear text?

My current idea is simply to store the refresh tokens in a file and to store the access tokens in Session.

Answer (score 1):

For a server application ([confidential client](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1)) that should be fine. You can use [DPAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) to encrypt the files to mitigate the risk of someone stealing them from your server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this also apply to a Client Id/Secret?

Comment: Yes, it does. Just don't use client id/secret on public clients (JavaScript/mobile).